# link between photo and thumb in shotwell (v 12, db schema 15, ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: shotwell, database, thumbnails

How do I find the corresponding thumb to a photo in shotwell, schema version 15?  The thumb files seem to have hex numbering that doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the photo table as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to use their generated thumbnails for images, instead of creating my own.  Any ideas?

Comment: Been a while since I looked at the code, but as far as I recall the thumbnail filename is simply the row ID from the database.  If you just want to generate small images from your Shotwell photos, it's probably easier to use the Export feature (File->Export) which lets you export the selected photo(s) at any size you like.

Comment: I'm planning on accessing it behind the scenes and don't want any user interaction or invoking of the application.

Comment: Keep in mind that the DB will get corrupted if you open it with write access while Shotwell is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's almost a year old, but I was trying to accomplish the same, and it's quite easy, so I thought I'll share my solution. The thumbnail file names are generated simply from the "id" field for an image's entry in PhotoTable. The id is stored as a decimal number, and you simply have to convert it to hexadecimal.

This will print out the filename to an image's corresponding thumbnail (replace $path with the full path to the image, or alter the match criterion according to your needs):

```
sqlite3 ~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db "select id from PhotoTable where filename = '$path'" | xargs printf "thumb%016x.jpg\n"
```